# c# LINQ Query: average value after group

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a datatable with a number of columns.

I want to group the date column and for each date, I want to work out the average value of the result column.

I have the following code which is not working as expected:

```
var results = from res in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      group res by res.Field<string>("operation_time")
                          into grp
                          orderby grp.Key
                          select new
                          {
                              date = grp.Key,
                              sum = grp.Average(r => r.Field<double>("result"))
                          };
```

Could somebody advise how I can do this?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: My bad.......I stupidly used the incorrect column name.  It's now working as expected.  Thanks.

Comment: If @Slaks's answer was correct, you should accept it, even if you also found the mistake on your own (I'm not the downvoter, BTW).

Answer (score 2):

You're sorting by the `operation_time` field as a string, which is unlikely to be what you want.

You should parse it into an `int` or `DateTime` using their respective `Parse` methods.